# any similar function like df.mask for tensor in pytorch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensor

I want to replace all 0s in a 2-D tensor with -5.

With dataframe, i can easily do this:

```
df = df.mask(df=0, -5)
```

but this does not work for tensors. I have tried:

```
 y = torch.where(y = 0, -5, y)
```

Answer (score 2):

it is simple, just use this

`y[y==0]=-5`

Comment: it is not a special function, just python standards

Comment: @LinmeiShang in general, many of the numpy tricks (related to indexing) are applicable to pytorch as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are two general ways.

One, given above by `prhmma` is to use in-place mutation like `y[y == 0] = -5`. It is nice and efficient, but will **break autograd operation**. So if you want gradient to flow through y, you should not do that.

The other is to use `torch.where`, as you have attempted. The proper incantation is

```
y = torch.where(y == 0, torch.tensor(-5), y)
```

or, if you want to be device- and dtype-agnostic

```
five = torch.tensor(-5, dtype=y.dtype, device=y.device)
y = torch.where(y == 0, five, y)
```

the fact that `where` does not accept scalars is an annoying papercut, but that's how it is ATM. Note that while the choice itself is discrete and obviously not differentiable, this operation will let gradients flow through both operands.

Comment: no matter what the piecewise function `y = -5 if x == 0 else x` isn't going to be differentiable at 0, it's not even continuous. So valid backprop is out of the question

Comment: The above comment is just to highlight this important fact that you already mention in case @LinmeiShang plans on using this for optimization purposes.